# cast List to ArrayList

Tags: java, collections, casting

When I want to cast the `ArrayList` object in `List` reference that returned from the method:

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}
```

The return type from the method `asList` is a `List` reference to `ArrayList` object, which means I can cast it to `ArrayList` reference.
Such that :

```
String[] colors = { "black", "blue", "yellow" };
ArrayList<String> links = (ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList(colors) ;
```

But this code made run-time error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Why it's happened?

Comment: ArrayList that is returned from Arrays.asList is not an actual arraylist, it is just a wrapper... which doesnt allows any modification in the list

Comment: what you mean of "wrapper" ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption that you can cast it to ArrayList is not valid.

The `ArrayList` is concrete type that implement `List` interface. It is not guaranteed that method `asList`, will return this type of implementation.

In fact the used type is `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`.

Using concrete class instead of interfaces. Can be recognized as bad practice. This approach is better when you have special type of class and you want to give a hint for future developer that this type is dedicated for the task.

But the API should exposed in the most abstract way. That is why the `List` was used.